# Objective C/Xcode error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

I hope this error doesn't sound stupid.

However, I receive this error and I don't know how to fix it. What happen is that I deleted the whole Resources folder before and copied in a new Resources folder. Could anyone help me fix this? Thanks.

ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/tohchinsheng/Documents/cocos2d-output/Debug-iphonesimulator/Untitled.app/Info.plist Resources/Info.plist
cd /Users/tohchinsheng/Desktop/Untitled
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-infoPlistUtility Resources/Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/tohchinsheng/Documents/cocos2d-output/Debug-iphonesimulator/Untitled.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/tohchinsheng/Documents/cocos2d-output/Debug-iphonesimulator/Untitled.app/Info.plist

error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Comment: Added iphone related tags, since the question is completely general until you read the path directories and realise that it's to do with iPhone dev...

Answer (score 2):

The Resources file you deleted contained an Info.plist file that held info that your app needs. I guess the obvious solution is to just copy the info.plist file to your new resources folder.

If you deleted the other resources folder... then I suggest you start a new xcode proj with the same name as the proj you are tyring to fix and copy that new info.plist file to your working project resources directory