# Plist file doesn't exist on appium when triying to run an ipa to test

Tags: python, ios, testing, appium

I am having some troubles while running a `Python` script on `appium`. The error I am getting is this:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown
>   server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
>   error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Plist file
>   doesn't exist:
>   '/var/folders/sv/jgqwxc7n6450d0qf6qt_2kb80000gn/T/2016417-819-1j76sd2/appium-app.app/Info.plist'

I am running the script on `mac OSX` and I am using an `iphone 5s` for testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Info.plist Utility Error: "Info.plist couldn't be opened because there is no such file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189404/info-plist-utility-error-info-plist-couldnt-be-opened-because-there-is-no-suc)