# Error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, plist, file-not-found

I have move my project from another machine with latest Xcode installed in it. But now when i'm running project it giving me error as

> Info.plist:0: error: reading data: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be
>   opened because there is no such file.

Previously project running with no issue but now on new system project has error. Previous version was Xcode 7.3.

Comment: Check the path of `Info.plist` in Build Settings. It's a relative path and probably doesn't match the new location.

Comment: find `info.plist` file & `Remove reference` from project & add that file again to project.. This worked for me...

Comment: Tried both way but no success yet...

Comment: duplicate question see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189404/info-plist-utility-error-info-plist-couldnt-be-opened-because-there-is-no-suc

Answer (score 11):

This error happens when the system can not locate the info.plist file from your file hierarchy.

**Consider this situation:** I moved the info.plist file to the group "Others" like this..

[image]

Goto Target - Tap Build Settings - Find "info.plist"

[image]

Here, the system will search the info.plist in AddModifyDelete folder. But the actual file is under AddModifyDelete/Others. So, change it to AddModifyDelete/Others/info.plist

Now it should work!!

**Note:** This is also applicable to entitlements file. We should define the right path for both info.plist & entitlements file to avoid this error.

Comment: @Thor Welcome :)

Answer (score 10):

Please try either of the two ways :-

First Try :

The solution for this particular instance of the error was “Info.plist couldn't be opened because there is no such file” was that I had deleted all of the files in the "Project Tests" folder, but was still had "Project Tests" listed under my targets. After deleting the "tests" target, the project built successfully.

Last Try :

1) Go to :- App Target 2) See the Identify ---and choose the Plist

Comment: Hey lalit , is your previous machine is available from where you shifted your code.If it is available copy the plist from that code and remove the reference from here and paste it.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you then vote me up.

Answer (score 0):

Error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. This error occurs when you change the location of the Info.plist file. To fix this issue, follow the below steps.

1. Go to the navigator pane.
2. Click on error symbol located near to the project name.
3. It will open the analyze screen.
4. Click on Choose Info.plist file.
5. Select Info.plist and click on choose button.
6. Click on product option and clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

**Or you can try**

Maybe your plist has incorrect format, because of a conflict from git pull, so you should open your .plist file with text editor and resolve the conflict, and then reopen your project with Xcode, everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Target
2. Goto Build Phase
3. Remove **.Plist** File from **Copy Bundle Resources**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use these commands in terminal
1.pod deintegrate
2.pod clean
3.pod install