# Reading data: The file "Info.plist" couldn't be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11, info.plist

After cloning my Github repo, everything runs fine except the build fails because of this error "Reading data: The file "Info.plist" couldn't be opened because there is no such file."

I have tried every possible solution I could find, including deleting the file and creating a new one, deleting it from the Copy Bundle Resources, adding it to the Build Settings, etc. I have followed these posts among others on all of the solutions but nothing has worked. [Error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675044/error-the-file-info-plist-couldn-t-be-opened-because-there-is-no-such-file),  [Info.plist Utility Error: "Info.plist couldn't be opened because there is no such file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189404/info-plist-utility-error-info-plist-couldnt-be-opened-because-there-is-no-suc)

I would really appreciate someone's help in finding a solution to this problem, and if you need any more information, please let me know.

**Edit:** Also for some reason when I looked in the project it's not the newest version that I had committed to Github. I was wondering how I can clone an exact commit? I was trying to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555107/git-clone-particular-version-of-remote-repository) but I'm not exactly sure where to find the remote address?

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991851/3146021) to know the remote address. Get the newest commit, clean and build project again. Try to this first and let me know if still have error

Comment: @TraiNguyen how would that look for example typing in a commit?

Comment: unsure about your question but as i know, should go to the web contain your source code, like github, bitbucket, ... , check how many branch you have, and see what is newest commit of each branch, it so easy for looking than in terminal - i think :)

Comment: Try to remove `$(SRCROOT)/` from Bundle Settings (`INFOPLIST_FILE`)

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you say this doesn't work, are you talking about when you run this from a clone in a different directory? Or to put another way, if you copied your project to another directory, will it work or fail?

Comment: @MobileBen I mean that when I cloned the project from GIthub, I would get this problem and nothing I tried would work.

Comment: When you clone it, are you cloning to a new directory or to one with the *exact* same path? I'm asking this because there is a chance you have a hard coded path which is doing it (which is why I'm asking these q's). Also if you click on your target in the Project Navigator and click on the Info section ... does it show your info plist information?

Comment: Did you check the path of info.plist in all your target? ex.: Test, Pods.....

Comment: 1/ check your branch: git branch -> is it the one you'd expect, 2/  search your plist file: git ls-files | grep plist -> is it were you expect it to be? How does that compare with the build message, is it the same path?

Answer (score 1):

***Update***: Although it is not important how the info plist file is named physically in your project, because Xcode renames it always into Info.plist during product bundle creation phase, but to avoid confusing among community, let's assume that your info plist is named Info.plist.

Check the followings:

1) Is Info.plist present in file system after clone?
2) Is correct related path is set for Info.plist in project Build Settings (`INFOPLIST_FILE` tag)?
3) Is Info.plist file not damaged - opened by Xcode as a document  (Info tab in project settings should show it as well)?

Note: Info.plist should not be added in target's Resources, it is copied by Xcode from mentioned above `INFOPLIST_FILE` (and renamed if needed into Info.plist!)

Comment: That is correct. It is not damaged, everything shows as it should. The file shows up in the file system (as in the project like a file in Finder with all the others), the path is correct in the Build Settings, and it's not in the Resources (is that the Resources Tag?)

Comment: is it public repo? can you give a link?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant. It's private. I'll be more than happy to give you any information you need. I didn't have this problem before but I had to delete Xcode to get storage to update to Catalina, and after that when I tried to clone the project I don't get the newest commit (by like 6 months) and I get this problem.

Comment: It should be `Info.plist` not `info.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be pretty difficult to debug this without having a look at your project, if all fails you might consider making a copy, remove all source files and share that shallow copy on a public repo.

Otherwise, on top of what @Asperi had already said, be sure to:

1. Clean build folder before each try you make to fix this (Command+Option+Shift+K), just in case
2. Open the build logs (see below) and using the search (Command+F) look of an entry that starts with `ProcessInfoPlistFile`. Check if there's something wired with the path there, check if the file pointed by that path is missing, if it has the right project name etc
3. If you're building multiple targets, be sure to check if **each** has a valid `.plist`, not just the main one.
4. Open `yourprojectname.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` in a plain text editor (e.g. write `open yourprojectname.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` in terminal) and search for `Info.plist`, be sure that each entry has a valid path (the path specified there actually exists)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following applies to the **question**, **comments** and **answers** here:

`Info.plist` **[should be capitalized](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1)** — if not it could easily explain your problem.

> <sub>**NOTE**: Several comments and answers are using lowercase <strike>`info.plist`</strike>,
>   this just adds fuel to the fire. It's *best* to **be specific** (especially when
>   it comes to this), because that minor detail can make a huge
>   difference.</sub>

**The answer awarded the bounty is absolutely false information**. The following excerpt comes directly from the documentation previously linked:

> **Important:** In the sections that follow, pay attention to the capitalization of files and directories that reside inside a bundle. The NSBundle class and Core Foundation bundle functions consider case when searching for resources inside a bundle directory. Case mismatches could prevent you from finding your resources at runtime.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1

Comment: It does not matter how the project info.plist file is named if you use `INFOPLIST_FILE` and not copy it manually. Xcode will rename it automatically into Info.plist during build.

Comment: @Asperi: **It does matter as it states that the case is important directly in the documentation.** if you solely rely on a tool to correct your mistakes that’s bad practice.